# Multidimensional array x86

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I know how to do this in C++ but in x86 I can not seem anywhere to declare say a 4x4 array. I am just looking for an example to get me started.

Comment: I'm confused. C++ is a programming language. x86 is a CPU family...

Comment: x86 assembly language is what I am trying to use here

Comment: Didn't know that was a thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assembly language doesn't have the concept of a "multidimensional array", at least not directly. You will need to allocate the total amount of space (16 elements in your case), and handle the row/column offset calculations yourself.

Comment: I understand. I have been trying to read through the following link http://webster.cs.ucr.edu/AoA/Windows/HTML/Arraysa2.html , but I am getting more confused then before. Do you happen to have any other resources that might assist?

Comment: Hey, that looks like a great reference, it's the sort of thing I would have pointed you at if you hadn't said that you already were looking at it. Do you have any specific questions we can help with?

Comment: I know how to declare a 1 dimensional array `array BYTE val1, val2, val3, val4` but I am having a hard time understanding how to go about doing that for a 4x4 array

Comment: Well, one way would be `array BYTE val11, val12, val13, val14, val21, val22, ..., val43, val44` (16 values in total). Then, to index into the array, multiply the *row* value by 4, add the *column*, and offset that into `array`.

Comment: I see it makes more sense now. So declare a 1 dimensional array but arrange the values in such a way it can be treated as  4x4 still. That is exactly what I needed. Thank you!